# Oracle Map Builder shapefile import failure

Tags: file, import, oracle10g, geospatial, shapefile

[I have a shapefile that contains regions geospatial data.](http://earth.unibuc.ro/file_download/1252)

I have two Oracle 10g server instances one in a Windows xp virtual machine and one on my laptop with Windows 8.1. The import using Map Builder on the virtual machine runs without problems, but the import on my windows install does not work. The steps I followed are:

1. I have tried to import this file using the option "Import Shapefile" from Oracle Map Builder.
2. I have uploaded the file, and then I set the SRID: 31700 that's the SRID for Romania.

The error is:

> Not all shapefiles been imported.
>
> Imported 0 of 1 shapefiles.
>
> See log for additional details.

Mapbuilder is just a `.jar` file and I didn't found any log file.

When I check the table created in the database there is only one record from 42 records. I also tried to export as `file.sql` the table from Oracle xp instance but when I try to import the table i get the following error **"ORA-00939: too many arguments for function"**.

Why the Map Builder gives that error although the Map Builder and Oracle versions are the same?

Answer (score 0):

Find the log file. Use process explorer - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx. This nice utility will tell you where map builder is trying to create the log. Once you have the log file you'll probably find the relevant error there.